# find if any number in A.P can be divided by a given number(k).

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

If there is any method other than finding each number of A.P iteratively and check if it is divisible by k or not?

Example :

Tn = 11*n+d;

k = 7;

find if (Tn % k == 0) ?

Comment: Rewritten... you ask if there exist solutions to $11n+d\equiv 0\pmod{7}$...  In the case that $11^{-1}$ exists, absolutely.  $n\equiv 11^{-1}\cdot d\pmod{7}$.  Here, $\gcd(11,7)=1$ so $11^{-1}\pmod{7}$ exists.

Comment: For the general case, let $T_n = a\cdot n + d$ so you have common difference $a$.  In the event that the common difference between terms in your A.P. is not coprime to $k$, then a bit more work is necessary.  See if you can simplify it first by dividing some until $a$ or $d$ is coprime to $k$.  If you end with $d$ coprime to $k$ while $a$ is not then no solution exists.  $T_n = 7n + 1$ is never divisible by $14$ for instance.  Otherwise, if you end with $a$ coprime to $k$ there is always a solution and it can be found again as $-a^{-1}\cdot d$

Comment: I don't get you on the part where you said simplfying it untill a or d becomes coprime to k.Since a and d is constant integer and n is integer variable. we can easily compute if a or d is coprime or not. what to divide?

Comment: Take for instance asking if there exists an $n$ such that $100n + 15\equiv 0\pmod{25}$.  That is, asking if there exists some integers $m$ and $n$ such that $100n+15 = 25m$.  Dividing both sides by $5$ we see that this is equivalent to asking if there exists some integers $m$ and $n$ such that $20n + 3 =5m$ which is equivalent to asking if $20n+3\equiv 0\pmod{5}$.  There isn't because $\gcd(3,5)=1$

Comment: what about the cases where both a and d would not be coprime to k?

Comment: You divide again...

Comment: lets say a = 2,  d = 3 and k = 5 and it would be like 2n+3 mod 5, we can't divide any further but there is solution when n = 1.

Comment: $2$ *is* coprime to $5$, and so since $a$ (*after the necessary divisions*) is coprime to $k$ we  have that there are solutions, and those solutions are precisely those $n$ such that $n\equiv -a^{-1}d\pmod{k}$

Comment: I got the idea. however, I am not familier with the notation that you have used for n. I meant, what is −a−1d (modk) means. thanks anyway. this will give me a good head start.

Comment: This is standard notation of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$ means by definition that $x-y$ is a multiple of $n$.  Next, when considering modulo $n$ you have $x^{-1}$ is a number such that $x\cdot x^{-1} \equiv 1\pmod{n}$.  Note that when working modulo $n$, there are not fractions and that there can be zero-divisors, for instance $4\cdot 3\equiv 0\pmod{6}$ so $4^{-1}$ doesn't exist when talking about modulo $6$.  (*else we'd have had $0\equiv 4^{-1}\cdot 0 \equiv 4^{-1}\cdot 4\cdot 3\equiv 1\cdot 3\equiv 3\pmod{6}$ which is false*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collating comments...

$T_n = an + d$ will be divisible by $k$ if and only if

$an+d\equiv 0\pmod{k}$ if and only if

$a'n + d'\equiv 0\pmod{k'}$ where $a' = \frac{a}{\gcd(a,d,k)}, d'=\frac{d}{\gcd(a,d,k)}$ and $k'=\frac{k}{\gcd(a,d,k)}$

if and only if $(a')^{-1}$ exists in $(\Bbb Z_{k'},+,\times)$

if and only if $\gcd(a',k')=1$

if and only if $n\equiv (-d')\cdot (a')^{-1}\pmod{k'}$

---

Examples:

Asking what values of $n$ are such that $T_n = 11n+5$ is divisible by $7$, we have that $\gcd(11,7)=1$ that $11^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod{7}$ and $(-5)\cdot 11^{-1}\equiv 4\pmod{7}$ so we find that every $n$ of the form $7m+4$ will be such that $T_n$ is divisible by $7$.  (*Indeed, $T_4=49=7\cdot 7,~T_{11}=126=7\cdot 18,~T_{18}=203=7\cdot 29,\dots$*)

Asking what values of $n$ are such that $T_n = 60n + 6$ is divisible by $30$, we look instead at which $n$ are such that $10n+1$ are divisible by $5$, but since $\gcd(10,1)\neq 1$ while $\gcd(1,5)=1$ we see that there are no solutions.

Finally, asking what values of $n$ are such that $T_n = 8n+4$ is divisible by $12$, we look instead at which $n$ are such that $2n+1$ is divisible by $3$.  Since $\gcd(2,3)=1$, $2^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $(-1)\cdot 2^{-1}\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ we have that every $n$ of the form $3m+1$ works.  (*Indeed, $T_1=12, T_4=36=12\cdot 3, T_7=60=12\cdot 5,\dots$*)